# Are there any other Scarlet Witches in the Multiverse?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

In Doctor Strange the Multiverse of Madness, we see Wanda as Scarlet Witch

> after using the Darkhold and later destroying the Darkhold in each universe.

Doesn't that mean there is no other Scarlet Witch in the whole Multiverse? If yes, does that mean that the one Scarlet Witch would be the one from the "What If" series?

> The Zombie Scarlet Witch? Telling that Zombies will infest Universe 616?

Comment: Do you really need the spoiler boxes?

Comment: This book has hardy anything to do with her being "Scarlet Witch".

Comment: @taylor.2317 I just didn't want to spoil stuff for people

Comment: @Mithoron - that's interesting, I understood that she became the Scarlet Witch just after she got the Darkhold & enhanced her powers because of that.

Comment: @Edwin _"this is Chaos Magic, Wanda. And that makes you the Scarlet Witch."_ Agnes says this to Wanda before Wanda gets the Darkhold from her and about actions Wanda has done in the past. The Darkhold does not make her the Scarlet Witch, she was already.

Comment: Then what was the role of the Darkhold and the throne? Because in the end she needed America for doing more.